# How to use a variable in other Class to repeat something? (Java)

Tags: java, class, oop, variables, inheritance

I'm programming in Java to do a simple program to simulate something as the Facebook menu just to practice Object-Oriented Programming. Here's the thing;

In a Class called ''Decision'' the user enter '0' to Exit, '1' to Sign Up or '2' to Log In.

I want the program to go back to the main menu after the user Sign Up or Log In because in the code below when the user neither Sign Up or Log In the program ends.

The variable used is called ''option'' and I think I have to use it in the main Class to do what I want (repeat the main menu).

Here's my code:

```
class Decision { // THIS IS THE CLASS FOR ENTER THE OPTION.

    protected byte  option; // THIS IS THE VARIABLE.

    public Decision() {

        boolean aux = true; // THIS IS ONLY FOR VALIDATE WRONG INPUT.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\t*-------------------------------*");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t     FACEBOOK");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t*-------------------------------*\n");
                System.out.println("0.-EXIT FACEBOOK\n");
                System.out.println("1.-SIGN UP\n");
                System.out.println("2.-LOG IN\n");
                option = sc.nextByte();
                aux = true;
                if (option >= 3 || option < 0) {
                    aux = false;
                    System.out.println("\nPLEASE INSERT A VALID OPTION.\n");
                }
                if (option == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nSEE YOU SOON.\n");
                    aux = true;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
                aux = false;
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nPLEASE INSERT A VALID OPTION.\n");
            }
        } while (aux == false); // I USE THIS FOR VALIDATE THE INPUT, DO NOT
                                // WORRY AT ALL.

    }// CONSTRUCTOR
}// Decision

class Data extends Decision { // THIS IS THE CLASS FOR ENTER DATA (NAME, LAST
                                // NAME, ETC)

    Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void Title() {
        System.out.println("\n\t\t\t*-------------------------------*");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t     FACEBOOK");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t*-------------------------------*\n");
    }// Title

    public void Decision() {

        if (option == 1) {
            // IN THIS PART THE USER IS CREATING A PROFILE AND STUFF.

        } else {
            if (option == 2) {
                // IN THIS PART THE USER ONLY LOG IN AND THE SEE THE INFO.
            }
        }// else

    }// Decision

}// DATA

public class Facebook { // AND THIS IS THE MAIN CLASS

    protected Decision  option;

    public Facebook() {
        option = new Decision();
    }// CONSTRUCTOR

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Facebook facebook = new Facebook();

    }// main

}// Facebook
```

Comment: Top tip: Don't put logic in your constructors.  put it in methods.

Comment: `Data` is never used

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat something in a program, the natural answer should be for you to use a loop. Change your exit condition `aux == false` (which would better be `!aux`, it is equivalent but better programming style). For example :

```
// initialize it to false in case the first iteration of the loop throws an exception
boolean exit = false;
do {
    //...
    exit = option == 0;
while (!exit);
```